# Center align UITableViewCell's footer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How could I center align UITableViewCell's footer?

I've tried using the following code but it does not work:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UILabel *footerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    footerLabel.text = @"Centered text";
    footerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    return footerLabel.text;
}
```

I have also tried creating a UIView but I get an `Incompatible pointer types returning 'UIView *' from a function with result type 'NSString *'`

Answer (score 27):

This code will center footer text:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayFooterView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *footer = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;
    footer.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

It will match existing UITableView footer styles, and also handles device rotation and different widths properly without needing to mess with frames or constraints.

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what is needed to edit style of the footer view.

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 3:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let footer: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    footer.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
}
```

Worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:

```
    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{
UILabel *footerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    footerLabel.text = @"Centered text";
    footerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
return footerLabel
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the following code works, but the label seems to be cut of horizontally. Moreover, is there a way to get it to look like the style of a UITableView's footer?

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 2/3/4+** one line safe solution:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    (view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView)?.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayFooterView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let footer: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    footer.textLabel?.textAlignment = .center
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is shortest:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayFooterView:(UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)footerView forSection:(NSInteger)section {
    footerView.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use `tableView:viewForFooterInSection` - it expects a view (which can be your label).